# How many $p$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3.\ldots,p\}$ are there, where the sum of whose elements are divisible by $p$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. How many $p$-element subsets $A$ of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,p\}$ are there, the sum of whose elements are divisible by $p$. It is the problem. It seemed easy but I can't proceed. Somebody please help me.

Comment: There is only one $p$-element subset of the given $p$-element set to begin with, isn't it? - Its element sum is $\frac{p(p+1)}2$ and hence a multiple of $p$

Comment: It seems obvious. What have you tried?

Comment: As commented above, it seems that intended question of  OP is different.Somebody please edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your problem is:

> For $1 \leq  n \leq  p$, find the number of $n$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\,\dots,p\}$ whose sum is divisible by $p$.

If $n=p$ then this number is 1 because the sum $1+2+\dots +p=\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ is divisible by $p$ (note that $p+1$ is even).

For $1\leq n<p$, try to show that the number of such subsets is 
$$\frac{1}{p}\binom{p}{n}.$$
Note that $\binom{p}{n}$ is the number of all $n$-subsets of $\{1,2,\,\dots,p\}$.